# AddItem function does not seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql

I go this thing to sorta work but my AddItem function doesn't seem to work. I click the "add item" link on the products page and it takes me to the cart page. But nothing is on the cart page. I am hoping somoneone can see it and tell me what to do to correct it.

The AddItem function:

```
function AddItem($itemId, $qty) { 
            // Will check whether or not this item 
            // already exists in the cart table.  
            // If it does, the UpdateItem function 
            // will be called instead 


            // Check if this item already exists in the users cart table 
            $result = mysql_query("select count(*) from cs368_cart where cookieID = '" . GetCartID() . "' and itemId = $itemId");
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
            $numRows = $row[0]; 

            if($numRows == 0) { 
                    // This item doesn't exist in the users cart, 
                    // we will add it with an insert query 
                    mysql_query("insert into cs368_cart(cookieID, itemId, qty) values('" . GetCartID() . "', $itemId, $qty)");
            }       
            else {  
                    // This item already exists in the users cart, 
                    // we will update it instead 

                    UpdateItem($itemId, $qty);  
                    }       
            }
```

I just checked my cs368_cart tables of the database and it is empty.

```
mysql> select * from cs368_cart
-> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So apparently nothing is being added. I am wondering if my query is correct?

My tables:

```
mysql> select * from cs368_products
-> ;
+--------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| itemId | itemName       | itemDesc                                    | itemPrice |
+--------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
|      1 | French Vanilla | A medium blend with a hint vanilla          |      9.79 | 
|      2 | Hazelnut Cream | A light blend with a spicy note of Hazelnut |      9.69 | 
|      3 | Columbian      | A medium-dark blend straight up             |      9.89 | 
+--------+----------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and my cart tables;

```
mysql> show columns from cs368_cart;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cartId   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| cookieId | varchar(50) | NO   |     |         |                | 
| itemId   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| qty      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my GetCartId I have in a seperate php file which is bieng called correctly by the php file with this AddItem function.

```
function GetCartId(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE["cartId"])){
    return $_COOKIE["cartId"];
}
else {
    session_start();
    setcookie("cartId", session_id(), time()+((3600*24)*30));
    return session_id();
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: What is the SQL going into the $result on your print page, you've given us the while loop but not what is actually being passed in.

Comment: @Truth Look, I have been at PHP/MySQL for approxiamately 2 weeks with a whopping 4 classes on it in an older book that did not mention PDO. I will definitely look at that. Thanks. I also appreciate the driveby with little help other than commentary.

Comment: @grahamrb I just edited the post, I was just thinking about that.

Comment: Actually, I think all the comments so far are *very* helpful to a new programmer. Don't take it personal. Here's a link (a bit old but still a good jumping off point) that helps with tracking down problems in code. Give it a shot and see if you can't at least narrow down the problem areas: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Comment: You should verify if the database is holding the entries you you inserting when adding to the cart, this will determine if the issue is with the insert or the display of the cart.

Comment: @grahamrb I just checked my table for the cs368_cart and it has nothing in it. Just out of curiousity, is this a valid mysql statement? `mysql_query("insert into cs368_cart(cookieID, itemId, qty) values('" . GetCartID() . "', $itemId, $qty)");` I blieve it is but like another perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to insert `cartId` as a string when your table has `cartId` as an integer. Take a closer look at your SQL in the PHP strings.

Comment: I changed my cartId to a varchar(100) in the table and that did not seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Actually I needed to change cartId to cookieId.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your insert query to something similar to below which will tell you what is wrong with your insert sataement (also it is good practice to handle any errors gracefully)

```
<?php
    $queryResult = mysql_query("insert into cs368_cart(cookieID, itemId, qty) values('" . GetCartID() . "', $itemId, $qty)");
if (!$queryResult) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

based on example in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Sorry, that did not do  thing. I did notice I had cookieID instead of cookieId. It was supposed to be the latter. Also a couple of other places in which I got that taken care of.